# FFT on high Audio Freqs

Tags: python, numpy, fft, pyaudio

Hi  I am trying  to plot fft data from real time audio input  for my project work  . I need to see the spectral components as I have to perform some actions based on frequency response   the code that I am modifying is based on here

http://flothesof.github.io/pyqt-microphone-fft-application.html

I am interested in frequency response around 18KHz  , and I am sampling at 44100 Hz   but the above code works only till 6800Hz   after that  it simply plots garbage .CHUNK size is 2048 .  what should I do to get frequency  around 18KHz.Also I dont see aliasing around 6800Hz on overshooting it.

This is my first question on stackoverflow am  sorry if it made you face palm . I dont have a DSP  background  but I am studying it on my own.

Thanks priest

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: The problem could be with the microphone or your system hardware audio filters.  Try a different mic on a different system.

Comment: If you sample at 44.1 kSa/sec you are right that you should expect frequencies as high as 22 kHz in your spectrum.The length of your sample in time determines the frequency resolution in Hz (1/sec) , i.e separation between different frequencies.  Try to make a minimal example (synthetic wave) to test your FFT routine, then post that if it still is not what you expect.

Comment: @ hotpaw   that can be the case will update it soon after testing.

Comment: @ roadrunner   the FFT does work  (I havent done what you have asked yet will do it soon )  . I generate a tone and see the plot for it ,I can verify that   in  <=6800Hz it works but after it its  garbage . peaks are on <1000Hz bins

Comment: @ paul   the code is working just not after 6800Hz . It may be that I screwed up my mic input